# Azure-DevOps Pull-requests: Honor previous approvals upon submitting new changes in latest iteration

Tags: azure-devops, branch, pull-request

I would like to ask for your help with steps to resolve a seemingly simple issue in regards with branch policies. We have the following requirement: Mandate at least 1 Pull-Request approval from a team member other than the code author. However, once the reviewer has added some comments for minor code changes to be made, and approved the PR, then for the next iteration on this PR we would like to retain the reviewer's previous approval vote so that the code author can complete the PR without waiting for any additional approvals for their latest code changes. We understand that if there are more critical code changes suggested by the reviewer, then they can simply vote to wait or reject the PR.

Could you please help provide steps to achieve this scenario to retain reviewer's approval votes over successive code iteration/s? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Github, do the following

1. Go to your repository
2. Click on the settings tab
3. Click on branches on the left
4. Edit the branch protection rules
5. Under "Require a pull request before merging" uncheck the box that says "Dismiss stale pull request approvals when new commits are pushed"

Edit: my bad, completely overlooked the azure devops tag. See if the following works for you

Under `Branch Policies`, set `Require a minimum number of reviewers` on, and uncheck the box that says `when new changes are pushed`.

Found documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-policies?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser#require-a-minimum-number-of-reviewers).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. We are using Azure DevOps so it appears that these steps may not be applicable.

Comment: See my new edit to the answer.